# What happens if the current ICAO method disagrees with double wheel/dual tandem etc?

Tags: airport, runways, landing-gear, icao, weight

Is the old U.S. method (a weight max for each landing gear kind) simply ignored? Planes with 3, 12, 14 and 22 wheels are common after all but gear types with those numbers often aren't listed. If the old way's ignored for 6, 10 and 18 wheels too then why's it often shown with the (soon-to-be replaced by ACR-
PCR) [ACN-PCN method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACN-PCN_method)? For example JFK has Pavement Classification Numbers from [90RBWT to 148FAWT](https://skyvector.com/airport/JFK/) (!) but the runways are all [210,000/550,000/1,000,000 lbs](https://skyvector.com/airport/JFK/) despite that vast strength difference (if a plane taxis from F to R and/or A to B its Aircraft Classification Number even gets worse). Another oddity is the 787-9 has 550,000-type tandems so old way would say it's too heavy till 11,500 lbs under MTOW but ACN-PCN says JFK runways are proof for fully-loaded 789s (90RBWT is obviously overkill for the relevant ACN of [71](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACN-PCN_method) and 60 on the 148FAWT runway is very overkill strengthwise (lengthwise it's OK for many landings but 1000' under nominal takeoff))

Comment: Welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com. This question could be improved by adding a bit more context. I understand it is about differences between ICAO and FAA regulations, and it has to do with wheels , weight and pavement classification, but that's about it. If you would quote the ICAO text and the (old) FAA text, and then explain what the inconsistency is, there is a much higher chance of getting good answers. Now you leave it up the readers to go throught the ICAO SARPS (several thousand pages) and the (old) FAA regulations (similar volume) and they have to guess what you are referring to.

Comment: It's about ICAO [ACR-PCR system](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/2022-05/508.RPA_P5_ACR_PCR.pdf) introduced by [amendment 15 to Annex 14](https://www.icao.int/WACAF/Documents/Meetings/2020/AAO-SG-3/AAO%20SG-3_WP4_AppA_Amdmts%20Annex_14%20and%20PANS__Eng.pdf)... (see next comment, due to url length)

Comment: ... related FAA AC are [150-5335-5D](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5335-5D-pavement-strength.pdf), and [150/5320-6G](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5320-6G-Pavement-Design.pdf). In the first document, FAA says: "An updated ADM Part 3 with the new procedures will
be posted in the near future"

Comment: Sorry about that. I added context.